What is the First Mint Tx of SOL?
It doesn't look like solana's Genesis block, and I didn't find any record related to it

The first accounts holding SOL were defined at genesis, so it was never "minted" -- it was just in all of the accounts when the cluster was started.
You can see them all at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/genesis/src/genesis_accounts.rs
